# Как вывести BitArray с помощью 1 и 0?

Tags: c#

Дан BitArray Result_bin, в котором находится (false, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, true). Как вывести его с помощью 1 и 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это нужно?

```
Result_bin[i]?"1":"0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", Result_bin.Select(x => int.Parse(x))));
```